# Can any one explain me about the fields of iphdr data structure in ip.h in network programming?

Tags: sockets, network-programming

What is iphdr data structure fields and what it is used for?

Answer (score 0):

`iphdr` merely contains the values of an IP packet header.

Refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header for details.